# Is there a convenient way to create these shape "confetti" effects?

Tags: shapes, sketch-app, flat-design

[image: Confetti style.]

So this is a super popular style I've seen recently, with geometric shapes/icons evenly spread out throughout the canvas to create an almost "confetti" effect. I was wondering if there's any "industry standard" way of doing this, or like a plugin or something that allows users to select multiple shapes and then have them coped and spaced evenly throughout the artboard?

At the moment, the only way I know how to do this is to manually spread them around, but this often yields results that aren't quite even, and there's an imbalance of various icons and colors. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sketchconfetti.com/

Maybe this plugin can help. I haven't used it myself, but I hope it is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(Face Palm, I finished my answer then realized you are using Sketch not Photoshop, hopefully you have the ability to use similar steps with Sketch, if not hoping this will help others with a similar issue using Photoshop lol)
[image: Example image of completed steps with text]

This may not be as automated as you were hoping for, but I do know of a way you could achieve this effect. I am just going to answer under the assumption that you don’t have specific shapes/icons in mind and that this would be used as a background image for a website (judging by your example image). Okay I’m just going to lay this out steps style.

1. Go to the website Subtle Patterns
2. Pick a pattern that you like, I’m using “Geometry 2” in my example
3. Download the pattern folder and open the png image (mine is named “geometry2”) in Photoshop.
4. Make a pattern out of the image by following these steps:
   Click on Edit > Define Pattern > Enter a name for the pattern
5. Make a new Photoshop file for your background image (mine is sized 1920 by 1080 )
6. Apply the pattern by using these steps:
   Click on create new fill or adjustment layer > Pattern > Click the pattern drop down menu to find the pattern you made then click it > Adjust the scale if you wish (I’m going with 260%) > Click OK

**Note:** Remember you can use Subtle Patterns commerically, but you need to credit them. See this link for more info on that: https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/faq/

**Optional Step**
7. You are done unless you want no shapes in the middle as in your example image in which case you can follow these steps (as I did): Click on the eyedropper and hover over the main background color (mine is greyish) then click on the color to grab it > Click on the brush tool  > Paint over the middle of the page or wherever you want your text/buttons, and paint away any pieces of shapes that may be left behind